# Why use a Logger instead of cout?

Tags: c++, logging, cout

In most of the open source C++ code I can see that a logger like the Google logging library `glog` is used. But what are the advantages? The only advantages that I could find:

1. Logging is thread safe, so preferred for multi threading
2. You can choose severity levels

So If I am not doing multi threading and I don't need severity levels, is `std::cout` safe to use or should I still use a logger? Why?

Comment: (1) + (2) + (3) logging can normally be disabled + (4) you can separate normal output from logging output.

Comment: It's amazing that given C++ has three kitchen sinks and a bathtub, there isn't a `std::log` iostream that is externally configurable in various ways.

Comment: `cout` is usually used to write to standard output (although can be redirect). if it's all you need, then simply use it.

Comment: btw "severity levels" can also be achieved by something like `std::cout << DebugInfo{"something Here"};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a logger is typically more versatile than directly writing to stdout. A logger usually can be configured to write to stdout or to a file or elsewhere.

In general, directly using `std::cout` is not recommended for anything but toy programs. Consider you have a function

```
 void foo() {
      auto x = calculate_some_result();
      std::cout << x;
 }
```

Then this function is of very limited use: It can only write to `std::cout`, not to anywhere else. However, with just a tiny change it can, in principle, write the result anywhere:

```
void foo(std::ostream& out) {
      auto x = calculate_some_result();
      out << x;
}
```

Now the same function can write to a file, to stdout or to any other `ostream`. As such an output is typically used all across an application and it is beneficial to have application-wide configurations, a logger (often a global object) can be used instead:

```
 void foo() {
      auto x = calculate_some_result();
      LOGGER << x;
}
```

Comment: Being pedantic, stdout and stderr can be redirected to log files and is what typically happens on unix system daemons.

Comment: @doron if you have `void foo()` and `void bar()` both writing to `std::cout` then yes you can redirect `stdout`, but with `void foo(std::ostream&)` and `void bar(std::ostream&)` you can decide easily at runtime where to write, seperately for `foo` and `bar`, and for each single call of the function.

Answer (score 1):

A logger offers you more control - you can tune the severity threshold, you can decide where the logging goes to (e.g., a file, stdout, somewhere else), etc **without recompiling the program**.

If that is not a concern to you, and you're absolutely sure you'll always want the same output to stdout and will never want to tweak it (a least not without recompiling), by all means, go ahead and use `cout`.